# Canvas line not appearing on screen

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So ive created the line and the window pops up but the line isnt showing

I have literally tried everything and i dont really know what to do so far. Is it around the part where i initialize the canvas widget itself?

```
import tkinter as ttk
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from weather import rawdata
import time

root = ttk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
root.title("New window")

# -------------get date information---------- #

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%y")

# grab image

imagepath = "D:\\Programing\\BG_sky.jpg"
background_picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imagepath))
backgroundimage = ttk.Label(root, image=background_picture)
backgroundimage.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")


# ------------Make loop for weatherdata------------- #

# ------------build window ------------------#

date = ttk.Label(root, text=dt_string, font=('helvetica', 15))
date.place(x=100, y=300)

weather = ttk.Label(root, text=(rawdata), font=('helvetica', 15))
weather.place(x=190, y=300)

canvas = ttk.Canvas(root)

line = canvas.create_line(220, 350, 220, 100, fill="black", dash=(4, 4))


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the line showing up. The problem is that you haven't added the canvas to the window. You need to add the canvas to the window with `pack`, `grid`, or `place`.

Comment: do i add the .place() near the beginning where i intit the window or towards the bottom where i construct the rest of the window